# how to create an options list pop-up on click using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I did search for how to create an options list pop-up that appear on clicking anywhere in the page ( when we click in a random position on the page, the list of options pops up like the mouse right click popup menu ) using jQuery like this example :

[image]

finally, I did find the solution with **[jQuery contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/)**
and here is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-contextmenu/2.7.1/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="context-menu-one">

    <script>
            $(function() {
                $.contextMenu({
                    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
                    callback: function(key, options) {
                        var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
                     },
                items: {
                   "Home": {name: "Home", icon: "Home"},
                   "About": {name: "About", icon: "About"},
                   "Contact": {name: "Contact", icon: "Contact"},
                   "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                         return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                     }}
                }
            });

            $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
                console.log('clicked', this);
            })    
        });
    </script>
    just right click
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: I am new with jquery, so I m searching for some information about how to create this type of drop-down  list.

Comment: Have a read of: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @freedomn-m  thank you for reminding me, but I did search about it here in stack and on other sites and what I always find is a drop down lists related to a button

Comment: In order to get good quality answers, please edit your question to include what you have tried so far. That way we can know at which point you've been stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague. I assume that you want to dynamically build a combo box and populate it with pre-set values, and append it to some element in the page. Here is one way of doing that.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
  var combo = $("<select />");
  var options = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  
  for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
    var option = $("<option />").val(i).html(options[i]);
    
    combo.append(option);
  }
  
  $('#result').append(combo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>

<button id="btn">Create Drop-Down List</button>
```

Comment: thank you, it did helps me with other issues, and sorry for being unclear in asking my question so I did edit it.